# Why doesn't "yes | head" hang?

Tags: unix, pipe, unix-head

Why doesn't `yes | head` hang?

I thought the system collects all of the result from `yes` and then pipes it to `head`, and because `yes` is an infinite loop, the system hangs.  But, it can actually stop and show 10 lines of `y`.

How does the system manage to stop `yes` when `head` is done collecting data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Pipe Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122/bash-pipe-handling)

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031344/why-is-this-pipe-terminated).

Comment: If you really need it to hang, use `yes | tail`. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `yes | head` the shell will arrange things such that the output of `yes` goes to a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) and the input of `head` comes from that same pipe. When `head` reads 10 lines, it closes its STDIN_FILENO, thereby closing its end of the pipe. When `yes` tries to write to a closed pipe it gets a `SIGPIPE` whose default action is to kill it.

A simple way to test this is with `strace`:

```
$ strace yes | head
y
[...]
y
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 4096) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=4069, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

Comment: The `-f` option isn't doing anything useful there. It looks like an attempt to trace both `yes` and `head`, but it doesn't do that because `strace` isn't a special shell builtin that can see a whole pipeline.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I wasn't aiming at tracing both; `strace -f` is just a reflex I picked up. I removed it, good call :-)

Answer (score 4):

> the system collects all of the result from yes and then pipes it to head

That would be extremely inefficient. When you use a pipe, the operating system creates a buffer for the pipe communication.

```
send | receive
```

As long as there's enough space in the buffer the sending process will write in it, and if there's enough data in the buffer, the receiver will process it. If there isn't the waiting process is blocked.

As soon as `head` finishes, the OS notices that it terminated, it will trigger a signal (`SIGPIPE`) which will terminate the sending process (unless the process handles it).

Comment: The final paragraph is sketchy.  The OS does not send the signal 'as soon as head finishes'.  Rather, when head finishes, the OS closes the  read side of the pipe.  When `yes` is rescheduled, it will (eventually) attempt to write into the pipe, at which point the signal is raised.  Consider the difference between `yes > /dev/null | true` and `yes | true`.